# How to convert T::Moment to u64

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    pub struct PayInstallmentOrder<Account, Balance, Time> {
        pub creator: Account,
        pub created_at: Time,
        pub periods_left: u8,
        pub paid: Balance,
        pub nft_id: [u8; 16],
    }
#[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;

        type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId> + Currency<Self::AccountId>;

        type NFTRandomness: Randomness<Self::Hash, Self::BlockNumber>;

        type WeightInfo: WeightInfo;

        /// Deposit required for per byte.
        #[pallet::constant]
        type DataDepositPerByte: Get<BalanceOf<Self>>;

        type Moment: Parameter
            + Default
            + Scale<Self::BlockNumber, Output = Self::Moment>
            + Copy
            + MaxEncodedLen
            + StaticTypeInfo
            + MaybeSerializeDeserialize
            + Send;

        type Timestamp: Time<Moment = Self::Moment>;
    }
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn get_installment_orders() -> Vec<PayInstallmentOrder<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, T::Moment>> {
            OrderByTokenId::<T>::iter_values().collect()
        }
}

// then I do tightly coupling in another pallet to call get_installment_orders() and take the created_at field in orders
```

I have this error when I try to convert T::Moment to u64 in the other pallet

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u64: From<<T as pallet_nft::Config>::Moment>` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/ocw/src/lib.rs:193:30
    |
193 |                 let y = order.created_at.saturated_into::<u64>();
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<<T as pallet_nft::Config>::Moment>` is not implemented for `u64`
    |    
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<u64>` for `<T as pallet_nft::Config>::Moment`
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::TryFrom<<T as pallet_nft::Config>::Moment>` for `u64`
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryInto<u64>` for `<T as pallet_nft::Config>::Moment`
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `UniqueSaturatedInto<u64>` for `<T as pallet_nft::Config>::Moment`
note: required by a bound in `saturated_into`
```

So how to fix this. Thanks for reading!

Comment: The `T::Moment` is an associated type and not a concrete type. The Moment type depends on what you give in the runtime pallet_nft config. So it's not a good solution to do `saturate_*` convert here.

Comment: Please provide links as reference for the specific types, traits, and source to give context in the form of a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just define Moment(associated type) in the following way:

```
type Moment: Parameter
        + Default
        + Scale<Self::BlockNumber, Output = Self::Moment>
        + Copy
        + MaxEncodedLen
        + StaticTypeInfo
        + MaybeSerializeDeserialize
        + Send
        + Into<u64>;
```

Take care of the bottom line "+ Into".

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!!